# Struct inside of same struct type?

Tags: c, struct

How can I have struct that contains a type of itself.

```
struct node { struct node *nodes[MAX]; int ID; };

struct node *node1, *node2;
node1 = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
node2 = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
node1->ID = 1;
node2->ID = 2;
node1->nodes[0] = node2;
node2->nodes[0] = node1;
```

There are no errors but the program doesn't execute correctly.

EDIT: I've added more of my code.

FINAL: It was a mistake in my part that I created an infinite recursion. I'll proceed to delete this threat. Sorry for your time spent.

Comment: You should post your code so we can see how you are trying to represent your graph.

Comment: Code looks OK, as far as it goes. Please provide more detail on what the problem is. How doesn't the program execute correctly? What are you expecting to happen? What's actually happening? More code would be good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are storing an array of *pointers* to the struct.  That's quite different.

You can't have the same struct inside itself.  That would be an infinitely recursive definition.

Now, if you would show more of your program we may be able to help you understand why your program doesn't run the way you expect.  Chances are you have not initialised the pointers because of confusion over exactly what they are.

**[edit]** Now that you have posted some code, and ignoring that you haven't said exactly what is going wrong, I expect that you are trying to iterate over the entire pointer list while examining your graph, but you never initialised it.

When you `malloc`, the memory will be uninitialised.  Standard practice in C is to use `calloc` instead which will set all bytes to zero.  Since you seem to be using the `nodes` array as a list, you may want to add a `num_edges` field to the node and make a function to do a two-way join on two nodes.

```
struct node {
    int num_edges;
    struct node *nodes[MAX];
};

int join( struct node *a, struct node *b )
{
    if( a->num_edges >= MAX || b->num_edges >= MAX ) return 0;
    a->nodes[a->num_edges++] = b;
    b->nodes[b->num_edges++] = a;
    return 1;
}
```

You could also test whether there is an edge from `a` to `b` like this:

```
int has_edge( struct node *a, struct node *b )
{
    int i;
    for( i = 0; i < a->num_edges; i++ ) {
        if( a->nodes[i] == b ) return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I want to create a graph, and so each node should be pointing to another node. What can I do about it?

Comment: `struct Graph{ struct node *root; }`

Comment: `struct node { char id; struct node *next; }`

Comment: Isn't this the same as mine without Graph? What's the difference?

Comment: You can store an array of nodes in your program like this: `struct node nodes[MAX]`.  Then you can set all the pointers to NULL and link up the ones that are connected.  This is a little redundant, but it would work.  There are many ways to represent a graph.  That may be beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: @drum You *can* have a pointer to the same struct within a struct, how else could lists be implemented in C?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen you have implemented a list, not a graph.

Comment: @paddy What do you think a graph is? It is a set of vertices connected by pointers. My example only allows a single edge leaving a vertex, but it should be a decent starting point

Comment: @HunterMcMillen A list is a special case of a graph.  A graph is not a list.  The user wants a graph, and is clearly already confused.  Giving them a list and calling it `Graph` is going to confuse them more.

Comment: @paddy Props to you for having the same functions I also have. In fact, it's as if you peeked at my screen! I won't delete the question anymore because of the usefulness of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is perfectly valid - having *pointer* to the same struct inside the struct is ok.